# How do I fix NU1002: Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.Abstractions does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0

Tags: dnx

How do I fix this error?

DNX Core 5.0 error NU1002: The dependency Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.Abstractions 1.0.0-rc1-final in project CSharp.Tests does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.

In projects.json I have

"frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": {
      "compilationOptions": { "define": [ "PORTABLE" ] },

How is Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.Abstractions being referenced? I have no idea... oh wait, maybe its this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aha! When I restart Visual Studio I see this!

[image]

Clicking the Yes button looks like it will help.